# Having a static header/footer with dynamic content

Tags: php, ssi

Ok so even I'm not too sure about what I'm asking, this is a whole part of web development I'm yet to look into.
I want to have a static header/footer with dynamic page content. I.E my header and footer stay constant throughout every page of my website, whereby the links to different pages on my website can contain pure content (no header or footer!) for easy editing?

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think I can do this with php includes. Am I correct and is there any other better way?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP includes are pretty much the standard way, yep.

```
include "header.php";
echo "Hello World"; 
include "footer.php";
```

(See [php.net's manual on include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), alternatively use [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php))

Note that your header / footer don't actually have to stay constant on every page, you could do checks for variables set beforehand or checks for what page the user is on.

```
$page = "contact";
include "header.php"; 
echo "Contact page stuff";
include "footer.php";
```

and in header, you could have "contact" in your navigation bolded or something `if ($page == 'contact'`. There's certainly other ways to do this (such as javascript or [$_SERVER variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)), but I use $page for other things so I like doing it that way.

Comment: Hey!
Could you expand a bit on your if ($page == $contact) function please? I'm not very good at PHP and since all 3 answers so far are pretty much the same, I think it'd be good justification for giving you accepted answer.
Thanks Alex

Comment: Yeah, sure. In my example, I declared $page before including the header, so `$page` could be used in header.php. In header.php, I could use that in lots of ways, such as having the `<title>` based on `$page`, like `<title><? echo ucfirst($page); ?></title>`. [ucfirst](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) capitalizes the first letter of a string, so the title would be "Contact" if $page = "contact". I could also do this in the navigation: `<li<?php if ($page == 'news') echo ' class="highlight"'; ?>><a href="./"> News</a></li>` which gives the option the "highlight" class on page news

Comment: @alex alternatively just leave $page as your desired title and do `<title><?=$page?></title>`, and for the navigation thing: you'd do similar checks for every `<li>` option and then add special css for class "highlight". Then, the user would get their current page in the nav emphasized. (Note that I'm using [php short tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) kinda inconsistently by accident). Edit: Oh oops, I meant to have `if ($page == "contact")`, not `$contact`, edited to correct.

Comment: I know that you're not supposed to use comments to say thanks, but I am anyway. Really helpful to a beginner.  
It's got the brain ticking about some new ideas for Javascript too.
Lastly, I tested your idea and it works (of course but I had to check just in case) :) have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that including, for example, a `header.php` and a `footer.php` at the beginning and end of your dynamic page.

If you want to explore some solutions better solutions like templating, I recommand you using something like Smarty : http://www.smarty.net/
See the doc. You can do things like `foreach` without including `<?php ?>` tags, and many others.

Answer (score 0):

### Basic site structure with the use of the [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) PHP function.

Site structure could look something like the following and could contain:

#### index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Page title</title> // this could contain <?php include 'title.php'; ?>
</head>

<body>

<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<?php include 'profile_content.php'; ?> // <-- contains your easy editing part

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>

</body>

</html>
```

#### header.php

Can contain your navigation menu, image header etc.

```
<div id="header" align="center">
<img src=\"/images/header.jpg border='0' \">
<p>
<a href="index.php">Home</a> - 
<a href="profile.php">Profile</a> - 
<a href="links.php">Links
</a>- <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
</p>
```

#### footer.php

Can contain your navigation menu including copyright information, author's name etc.

```
<div id="footer" align="center">
<p>
<a href="index.php">Home</a> - 
<a href="profile.php">Profile</a> - 
<a href="links.php">Links
</a>- <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
© Copyright Your name here <?php include 'date.php'; ?>
</p>
</div>
```

The date can also be dynamically changed, using an `include` tag for date.php for instance, using the [**date() PHP function**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

- Visit [PHP.net](http://php.net) and you can browse through their Web site for more information.

---

---